# Can one Yii application route to another one for use as a central admin app of multiple Yii apps?

Tags: apache, yii

I am creating multiple one-off sites on the Yii framework under one hosting account. The desire is to be able to create a one-off admin app that can be routed to by visiting the respective apps in a specific way.

For example, whether the website is app1, app2, or app3, I would like a visit to app1/admin, app2/admin, and app3/admin to route to app4 which is the administrative application.

Initially I was thinking of only having the one application and choosing different views for whatever the hostname was, but it is of complete importance that no asset files be reachable for a different site than what is being visited. However, the database will be accessed by all applications using slightly modified values depending on the requesting app.

If there are suggestions on a better implementation I am open to listen for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a common admin app, you could put an index file in each app, e.g., app1/admin/index.php etc and have that point to a common protected directory containing the shared amin app and either set an environment variable in the bootstrap file and/or do some checking by hostname to customize the admin views/data.

I'm not sure what kind of "asset files" you are utilizing and how you might be protecting them now (or even what you mean by "reachable") so it's hard to give input on that and it's also not clear if those assets are in the main app or the admin app, but you could also use Apache config or similar to alias the /admin directory to a common app with common public/web files or if you did use the Yii bootstrap to load a common protected directory, you could have separate public/web files for each admin app -- but non-php served files would need some kind of access filter.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now that it is mentioned. Simple and straighforward. The reference to asset files is to relate to images/css/videos/etc., asset files. However, the point of it being in my post was as to why rather than anything else. It was important that a visitor could just access img101.gif for website101 by going to website100/website101/img101.gif and seeing it.